# Magento 1.9, memory exhausted when calling cart.info api

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, api, xmlrpc

i tried to call cart.info api, but it said memory exhausted bla bla bla. Any idea to fix this ?

i've tried to increase the memory limit to 4 gb, but it doesn't seem to fix anything.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First of all a few pre-checks to be sure we are looking at the correct issue.

Have you checked in your phpinfo() if indeed your scripts run at 4gb memory. If not u should update your php.ini or .htaccess file to increase memory. for example, .htaccess

```
  php_value memory_limit 265M
  php_value max_execution_time 18000
```

If thats all ok, have your tried making a smaller query and does that work?

Be aware, if you run on a shared server, the hoster probably pinned you down on a X amount of memory. Having 4GB of memory does not say your php settings reflect that as well. if the php.ini, or .htaccess does not reflect you phpinfo(); response. Than you should contact your hoster.

Comment: hi Kay, thanks for replying, but your solution is not working, i changed the memory limit both in the php.ini and .htaccess, my phpinfo() said that the memory_limit is already 1G, and i also change the memory_limit in the .htaccess to 1G. my query is simple, i just want to get the shippingaddress from a quote. thats it. $quote->getShippingAddress()